# Trigger Ctrl+z & Ctrl+y keypress on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, undo-redo

I have provided two separates button for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.  I want the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> functionality to be performed on the click of a button.

To achieve this, I am trying to trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> on button click but they are not getting triggered.

The code I have written so far:

```
case "undo":
    var press = jQuery.Event("onkeydown");
    press.ctrlKey = true;
    press.keyCode = 90;
    jQuery(".excellentableEditSpread").trigger(press);
    break;

case "redo":
    var press = jQuery.Event("onkeydown");
    press.ctrlKey = true;
    press.keyCode = 89;
    jQuery(".excellentableEditSpread").trigger(press);
    break;
```

Comment: Remove `on` from Event type text, usage should be like `jQuery.Event("keydown")`

Comment: If you plan to trigger the browser "undo/redo" behavior I guess you can't do it using keyevent trigger. (same as you can't fill an input text with emulated keyevent)

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
function doUndo(){
  document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
}

function doRedo(){
  document.execCommand('redo', false, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work like`ctrl+z` or `ctrl+y` press.

```
case "undo":
    document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'z', 'ctrlKey': true}));
    break;

case "redo":
    document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'y', 'ctrlKey': true}));
    break;
```